# Does IE9 have browser mode down to IE7 and does this mean different version of Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble setting up virtual machines for testing IE versions (I use a mac) and have noticed on IE8 it has a browser switching mode.

Does this mode do a full switch for CSS and Javascript, I need testing to be 100% reliable.

Also does IE9 have a similar feature going down to IE7?

Comment: If anyone knows of a reliable standalone IE7 please let me know

Comment: Try this: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage  It contains the IE 5.5-9 engines all in one program.  Or you can download a Microsoft-made VM with IE 7 from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to be 100% reliable, I can tell you that right now.  The only way to *really* test on IE7 is to test on IE7. For most layout checks, using the newer browser in emulation mode will be fine, but there are definitely bugs and oddities in the actual older browsers that the newer browsers don't mimic faithfully.

Answer (score 1):

When you change The browser mode from the IE developer tools, IE renders the site according with your selection.

IE 9 also has this option, and if say you pick IE7, you'll get pretty much the same expercience you would get in that browser (from a layout and functionality point of view), but it's not completely reliable, some Javascript quirks are not the same (I can't remember any specific ones)

If you really need to test in IE7, get IE7 :D

More info [here!](http://petelepage.com/blog/2010/06/internet-explorer-developer-tools/)

Comment: Can anyone recommend a decent version of IE7 standalone the one I downloaded wouldn't let me enter forms!

Comment: @user1209203 Did you download this one http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2 ? .
Also you could try https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: @user1209203 You may download VM image with pre-installed IE from microsoft site, but you'll need to have license for some windows version.

Comment: Nico that's just the standard installer I want a standalone version to go with IE8

Comment: my bad, you're right. I normally use a different Vm for each one (a pain I know) so I don't really know a good standalone version. What I can recommend is http://spoon.net/ maybe you can use it in the meantime

Comment: @user1209203 :/, I suppose the standalone you have is this one: http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone . If that's the case in the comments they talk about your problem (ctr+f ->form) and it seems they solved it. If that doesn't work, I'll ask if someone knows another version and edit this post. Hope I helped you in some way. Good luck!

Comment: Well spotted I'll give that a go

Comment: @user1209203 I'm sorry, but I have to say, it feels a little bad that you accepted and upvoted another answer when I took the time to help you. Anyways, it's all good. Good luck :)

Comment: The answer I accepted is the answer I ended up using and I think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12, and in the developer tools toolbar change browser mode to IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 (if you change the browser mode, then doc mode automatically changes also).

[image: Screenshot of IE Dev toolbar]

As for whether you get a different Javascript API?  I don't know.

I agree with @Pointy, though.  Realistically you actually need to run IE7.  A VM is often a good way to do this if you don't want to muck about getting the different versions running side-by-side.